# Multiple inheritance and a heterogeneous collection

Tags: c++, polymorphism, multiple-inheritance

I have three classes that inherit from both `whirlyB` and `gameCreature`.  I am using all three sub classes in a collection of `gameCreatures`.  Is there a way to use the inherited functionality from `whirlyB`.  I am only given the choice of using `gameCreature` functions.  What should I do to get the functionality of `whirlyB`?

Comment: Please add the relevant language tag to your question.

Comment: @stmax would I then have to cast them back to gameCreature?

Comment: Presumably, your collection is of pointers (or perhaps references) to `gameCreatures`. If the collection is of `gameCreatures`, your values have had the `whirlyB` and other derived information sliced off before they were stored in the collection. You'll probably need to make a new class, `whirlyGameCreatures` which has the multiple inheritance from `whirlyB` and `gameCreatures` and then make the collection of pointers to `whirlyGameCreatures`. Your three leaf classes will inherit simply from `whirlyGameCreatures`. There will be some entertainment to be had managing the lifetimes of objects.

Comment: Can you modify your class definitions?

Comment: @stmax thanks, it worker.  Enter an answer and I can check you as having the correct answer

Comment: @Aaron actually it shouldn't work (correctly) in c++. you're probably getting some incorrect behavior in your program now when you're using the casted whirlys.. better look into kerrek's answer or even better try to change the design to remove the need to access whirlys where you only have creatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a silly idea, for the case where you're stuck with one of the base pointers but are free to modify the classes. Suppose we have:

```
struct InBetween : Rock, HardPlace { /* ...  */ }
```

and suppose that you only have `Rock`-pointers available. Edit `Rock` as follows:

```
struct Rock
{
    virtual HardPlace * get_other() const = 0;
    // ...
};
```

Now add to each derived class the following:

```
struct InBetween : Rock, HardPlace
{
    virtual HardPlace * get_other() const { return this; }
    // ...
};
```

Now, given `Rock * r`, you can say `HardPlace * h = r->get_other()`.

I wouldn't really call this good design, or even recommendable, but I think that's a literal answer to your question.